# What's the area of this square?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, word-problem

There's is a square with inner rectangles as in the diagram.

If the sum of perimeters of these 6 rectangles is 120 cm, what is the area in $\text{cm}^2$ of the square?

[image: Square]

Comment: And you are told that the figure is definitely a square, not a rectangle?

Comment: Hint:  In adding up the perimeters of the 6 rectangles to get 120 cm, which lines are counted once and which lines are counted twice?  Can you figure out what the perimeter of the square is?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the top of the square and it is broken into two lengths.  Call those $L_1$ and $L_2$.  And we know $L_1 + L_2 = s$ the side of the square.

Look at the side to the left.  It is broken into three heights.  Call those $H_1, H_2, H_3$ and we know $H_1 + H_2 + H_3 = s$.

Look at the side to right.  It is broken into three heights.  Call those $h_1, h_2, h_3$ and we know that $h_1 + h_2 + h_3 = s$.

To add up the perimeters of the six smaller rectangles we get:

$2(L_1 + H_1) + 2(L_1+H_2) + 2(L_1 + H_3) + 2(L_2 + h_1) + 2(L_2 + h_2) + 2(L_3+h_3) =$

$6(L_1 + L_2) + 2(H_1 + H_2 + H_3) + 2(h_1 + h_2 + h_3)=$

$6s + 2s + 2s = 10s = 120 cm$

So $s = 12 cm$.

Okay, that was more detail than needed.  All that we *needed* to notice was that in counting how many times the sides of the rectangles are counted to get the perimeter of the 6 rectangles.  The horizontal sides are counted six times; once for the top and bottom and twice for each horizontal bit in the middle.  Whereas the vertical sides are counted four times; once on the left and right and two times for the single vertical bit in the center.

(I made a mistake the first time I did this in that I both the horizantol and the vertical inside lines were counted the same number of times inside.)

....

where were we?  Oh, yes.

$s = 12 cm$ so $A = s^2 = 144 cm^2$.

Comment: I have each side of the square  $= 12 cm$

Comment: Yeah... I'm getting .... something wrong....

Comment: Yeah, I mistakenly assumed the each outside bit was represented twice  inside but the horizontal bits were represent twice inside but the vertical only once.

Answer (score 1):

As was already mentioned in a comment taking into account lines which counted once and twice one obtains:

$$
6a+4a=120\Rightarrow a=12 \Rightarrow a^2=144.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can align the perimeters and find out that the sum of the perimeters of the rectangles is $10$ times the base of the square. This means that the measure of the square's base is $12$ centimeters; therefore, area of the square is $144$ square centimeters.

Comment: The answer can only be a natural number of max 4 digits

Comment: The correct answer is 144 cm$^2$.

Comment: @user Please post an answer with detailed explanation

Comment: I'm not sure the answer is $\;144\;$ . I think taking into account all the lines that are counted four times (each of both upper horizontal lines), and those that are summed twice (each of the vertical ones: a pair on the left-center, and a pair on the right-center), we get $\;4x +2(2x)=8x\;$ , with $\;x=\;$ the square's side, so $\;x=120/8=15\implies A=225\;$ .

Comment: You aren't counting the inside lines tops of one rectangle AND bottom of another or left of one rectangle and right of another.  If you do, you actually count the sides *10* times.  Not just 7.  So it is $\frac {14400}{100}$ square centimeters.

Comment: " I think taking into account all the lines that are counted four times (each of both upper horizontal lines)"  This are counted *6* times.  Not 4.  "and those that are summed twice (each of the vertical ones: a pair on the left-center, and a pair on the right-center)"   So $6x + 2(2x) = 10x$.

Comment: @fleablood Yep, that's right: the middle lines are counted twice. Nice +1